# How to set values of HTML table cells

Tags: javascript, html

I have these 2 table cells. The one span is outside td, other is around td.

```
<tr height="30">
    <span data-name="toDD1" class="sstNumber"> </span>
    <td>Y</td>

    <span data-name="toDD2" class="sstNumber"> 
        <td>Y</td>
    </span>
</tr>
```

When I do the following code to set values, the values do not get updated.

```
document.querySelector('span[data-name="toDD1"]').value = "a";
document.querySelector('span[data-name="toDD2"]').value = "b";
```

So I am trying to set the values of toDD1 and toDD2 dynamically but I fail to do so. How do I do it? The above 2 lines don't help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: span has no value use html or text instead

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Comment: So I am trying to set the values of toDD1 and toDD2 dynamically but  i fail to do so. How do i do it? The above 2 lines dont help

Comment: You should read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question to help others give you quality answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't set the "values" correctly is because [HTMLSpanElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSpanElement) doesn't have a `value` property. You may notice that it inherits properties from [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) which has an `innerText` property you can set.

Since you indicated in the comments that you are trying to update the text in the `<td>` tags, you can move the `data-name` attributes from your `<span>` tags to the `<td>` tags and modify your javascript code to be:

`document.querySelector("td[data-name='nextDD1']").innerText  ='a';`
`document.querySelector("td[data-name='nextDD2']").innerText  ='b';`

https://jsfiddle.net/y0cdozv3/11/

Comment: Thanks. but the value gets set outside. do see the code here https://jsfiddle.net/6v0g9c14/1/

Comment: Are you trying to replace Y with A and B?

Comment: as seen here https://jsfiddle.net/7dnz3pau/, there are 2 tables cells. nextDD1 and nextDD2. I want to set a value into each of the 2 boxes